# I am not able to add the data in xampp database

Tags: python, database, tkinter, phpmyadmin

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import messagebox

import mysql.connector

from tkinter import Button


def ok():

    name = e1.get()

    salary = e2.get()

    dob = e3.get()

    mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="", database="sahil")

    mycursor = mysqldb.cursor()

    try:
        sql = "INSERT INTO clients(ID,NAME,SALARY,DOB) VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (name, salary, dob)
        mycursor.execute(sql, val)
        mysqldb.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("information", "record inserted succesfully..")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        mysqldb.rollback()
        mysqldb.close()


root = Tk()

root.title("client data")

root.geometry("400x400")

global e1

global e2

global e3

Label(root, text="NAME").place(x=10, y=10)

Label(root, text="SALARY").place(x=10, y=40)

Label(root, text="DOB").place(x=10, y=80)

e1 = Entry(root)

e1.place(x=140, y=10)

e2 = Entry(root)

e2.place(x=140, y=40)

e3 = Entry(root)

e3.place(x=140, y=80)

Button(root, text="ADD", command="ok").place(x=10, y=120)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi, please edit your question by to this post https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

it should be `command=ok` ...rather then `command="ok"`

Answer (score 0):

you dont show parts of your code, they would maybe interesting. but if you want to know how to use "Insert" with pythond and mysql here is one suggestion (this isn't on your code because you give less informations, but you can try this)

```
            cur_personen.execute("INSERT INTO person "                                      # INSERT INTO PERSON TABLE /
                             "(id, BLA, bLUB, Whatever, Nothing_fk)"              #
                             "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s) ",                                #
                             (                                                              #
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[0].get(),                     #
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[1].get(),                     #
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[2].get(),                     #
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[3].get(),                     #
                                 self.parent.optionbar.person[4].get(),                     #
                             ))
```